# Mandar variables a otro activity Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Estoy programando una App en la cual quiero que al apretar un boton envie variables a un Activity pero sin que se abra el siguiente activity, ya que es como un tipo carrito de ventas en donde se acomulan los productos.

Quiero que se abra el activity cuando el usuario quiera.

Gracias

```
public void pancakes(View v){
    control+=1;
    pedido.setText(control+"");
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Producto agregado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    t.show();
    String nombre = "Pancakes";
    double precio=60.00;
}
```

Este el código de mi boton, lo defino con onClick, y las dos últimas variables (nombre, precio) son la que quiero enviar al activity pero si abrirlo.

Y así tengo varios botones y lo que quiero es que se acumule la información y despues mostrarla en otro activity

Comment: Me parece un poco raro esto. Generalmente los carritos de compra funcionan con variables de session. Se supone que el carrito de compras es otra activity y cuando el usuario quiera ver sus productos, carga la activitys y ahi cargan todo.

Comment: Si pero como le mando los productos al otro Activity ?? Porque yo tengo un metodo para cada boton donde defino los valores que quiero mandar (Nombre, Precio), pero no tengo definido cuantos productos va a utilizar el usuario

Comment: Pero puedes armar un arreglo de productos y una vez que el quiera ver el carro, enviar ese arreglo como parametro y no 1 por 1. Puedes deja tu codigo? asi no te puedo ayudar mucho

Comment: Listo ya puse el código

Comment: @J.Torres agrego mi respuesta, **enviar un ArrayList de objetos entre Actividades no se puede realizar si tu objeto no implementa la clase Serializable.** http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/27997/95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te recomiendo yo segun lo que tu quieras es esto

```
public class Producto implements Serializable 
public class Producto(){
    String nombre;
    double precio;

   //Aqui haces los constructores y get and set
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    List<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<Producto>();
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      //Tu codigo
    }
    //Me imagino que la funcion de tu boton cuando agrega el producto
    Button addProducto= (Button) findViewById(R.id.addProducto);
    addProducto.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Producto producto = new Producto("Producto prueba", 60.00);
            productos.add(producto);
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Producto agregado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
        }
    });

    //boton para ver el carrito
    Button verCarrito= (Button) findViewById(R.id.verCarrito);
    verCarrito.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Carrito.class);
            intent.putExtra("Productos", productos);
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    });
}
```

En la otra activity

```
public class CarritoActivity extends Activity {
    List<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<Producto>();
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        productos =(ArrayList<Producto>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Productos");
    }
}
```

Comment: Y en un el otro activity como acomodo ese arreglo?

Comment: De igual manera, edito mi codigo.

Comment: Una pregunta, tu métod .add() se define en la clase Producto?

Comment: Que realiza el método .add()

Comment: No, el metodo add es propio de los objetos List o ArrayList

Comment: Gracias muchas gracias, me sirvio mucho

Comment: Me alegra haber podido ayudarte!

Comment: No es más optimo usar un parceable?

Comment: Si, tambien es una opcion! Como no tenia muy claro que hacer di este ejemplo!  Pero podria tambien hacerlo con parceable! Eso queda a la investigacion propia

Comment: @J.Torres Esto es **incorrecto si no implementas Serializable**. http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/27997/95

Answer (score 0):

**Lo que deseas es enviar objetos entre Actividades,** en este caso objetos Producto en un ArrayList, se realiza de esta forma, creas tu ArrayList de objetos y lo envias en el `Intent` mediante `.putExtra()`:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SegundaActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Productos", productos);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Para recibir el ArrayList de objetos Producto en la Activity se realiza de esta forma:

```
ArrayList<Producto> lista = (ArrayList<Producto>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Productos");
```

### Sin embargo existe algo muy importante que necesitas para realizar esto y es que tu objeto Producto debe implementar la clase [Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html):

```
public class Producto implements Serializable {
```

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas enviar a un activity, puedes sobrescribir la instancia Application de tu aplicacion y ahi puedes meter los datos que quieras, como tu carrito de compras, puedes ver como en este [link](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/inicio-android-2/#032)