# Cast ArrayList a String

Tags: android

Estoy recibiendo un arreglo de un Activity a otro asi:

```
List<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<Producto>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_carrito);

    productos = (ArrayList<Producto>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Productos");
```

y no me marca error, pero al momento de ejecutarlo me manda este error.

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Comment: J. Torres, agrega por favor como realizas el intent para abrir esta Activity.

Comment: Revisa como realizar lo que necesitas en esta respuesta http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/27997/95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a tu mensaje de error:

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Seguramente estas enviando un String y tratas de convertirlo a tipo ArrayList al recibirlo.

```
 productos = (ArrayList<Producto>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Productos");
```

---

Si vas a [enviar un ArrayList de objetos Producto desde una Activity a otra se realiza de esta forma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/27997/95).

Crea tu ArrayList de objetos Producto y lo envias en el `Intent` mediante `.putExtra()`:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Productos", productos);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Para recibir el ArrayList de objetos Producto en la segunda Activity, se realiza de esta forma:

```
ArrayList<Producto> lista = (ArrayList<Producto>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Productos");
```

Algo muy importante que necesitas es que tu objeto `Producto` debe implementar la clase [Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html):

```
public class Producto implements Serializable {
```

Answer (score 0):

He estado un poco alejado de Android pero buscando en la documentación de [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) veo que el método que usas regresa un objeto Serializable. Intenta usando el método [getStringArrayExtra(String name)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringArrayExtra(java.lang.String)) en lugar de getSerializableExtra(String name). También esta el método getStringArrayListExtra(String name), el cual regresa un objeto de tipo ArrayList, este objeto no puede ser convertido a ArrayList pero puedes tratar el array que te regresa e insertar nuevas instancias de Producto en tu arreglo producto.

Answer (score 0):

En el activity que envia la informacion

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SourceActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Productos", ArrayList<Producto>productos);
```

En la actividad que recibe deberia ser asi:

```
  ArrayList<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<Producto>();
  productos = (ArrayList<Producto>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Productos");
```

Comment: Gracias, una pregunta el "SourceActivity.this" Que es? y otra me manda un error cuando en el .putExtra() pongo List<Producto>productos Que puedo hacer?

Comment: "SourceActivity.this" en ese parametro le estas indicando al constructor del Intent que de esta actividad se esta enviando la informacion (En este caso el ArrayList) a la otra actividad que recibe "TargetActivity.class", ya arregle el problema del codigo.

Comment: Me sigue saliendo en el ArrayList<Producto>productos me aparece "Expression expected" Que puedo hacer?